# Is there an efficient way to execute a quantum channel using its Choi state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer, open-quantum-systems, quantum-teleportation

Consider you are given a Choi state
$$
\sigma = (\mathcal{E} \otimes I) | \omega \rangle \langle \omega| \qquad {\rm with } \quad |\omega \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{d}}\sum_{i} |ii \rangle \quad \textrm{generalized Bell state}
$$
corresponding to the quantum channel $\mathcal{E}$. Since the Choi state contains all the information about the quantum channel, one might think that it should be possible to efficiently execute $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$ on some state $\rho$ only having access to $\sigma$ and $\rho$.

I found two channel execution schemes that both use the identity $\mathcal{E}(\rho) = {\rm tr}_2(\sigma (I \otimes \rho^t))$, but both do not seem to be efficient:

1. is based on gate teleportation (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908010)
2. describes a heralded measurement scheme based on the eigendecomposition of $\rho$ (https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.05418).

(1.) In the gate teleportation scheme, we need to post-select on the exponentially suppressed state $|0...0\rangle$, if we do not want to apply $\mathcal{E}$. If the Choi matrix was unitary, we could try to compile the conjugation of the Pauli-String $U R_{xz} U^\dagger = R'_{xz}$ as described in the paper, but this would still require knowledge about $U$.

(2.) The heralded measurement scheme has a similar problem. (Following section III of the second paper) one can sample from $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$, but the expectation value will be exponentially suppressed. Resolving this also requires an exponential amount of samples, in general.

Is there an efficient way to implement channel execution with the described resources? Or is there a simple way of seeing why channel execution needs exponential resources?

---

EDIT: After a few iterations with @NorbertSchuch, I feel like I need to reformulate my question.

If we were to do state tomography (as suggested in the second paper), you would be measuring
$$
{\rm Tr}\left( \sigma (I \otimes \rho^t) \right) = \frac{1}{d} \mathcal{E}(\rho)
$$
with the transpose $\rho^t$ and $d$ the dimension of the Hilbert space. I am worried about the exponential factor $\frac{1}{d}$ (that I think, is missing in the paper), as it will lead to an exponential growth in variance of $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$ and therefore an exponential number of required measurements. Say, we are interested in measuring an observable $O$ on the channel output, then we calculate the expectation value
$$
{\rm Tr}\left( \sigma (I \otimes \rho^t) (O \otimes I) \right) = \frac{1}{d} {\rm Tr}\left( \mathcal{E}(\rho) O \right)
$$
Hence, to get the correct expectation value ${\rm Tr}\left( \mathcal{E}(\rho) O \right)$, we would need to measure $\tilde O = d O$ whose variance is inflated by an exponential factor ${\rm Var}(\tilde O) = d^2 {\rm Var}(O)$. Assuming ${\rm Var}(O) = \mathcal{O}(1)$, this means that we need to use exponentially many samples to resolve the expectation value.

On the other hand, if I could directly execute the quantum channel, I could directly prepare $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$ and sample ${\rm Tr}\left( \mathcal{E}(\rho) O \right)$ without exponentially many samples (a priori).

This goes against my idea of the Choi–Jamiołkowski isomorphism. It seems like, in the discussed case, it is always more favourable to directly execute the quantum channel instead of accessing it through its Choi state. Now my question is whether there is a better measurement scheme/technique that restores the symmetry between quantum channel and Choi state and gets rid of the factor $d$ or (if not) whether one can show that sampling from Choi states is exponentially surpressed.

Comment: What are the rules of the game? You get one copy of the Choi state and one of the input, and you want to know if you can apply it with unit probability? Or do you get several copies? Or do you know the state you want to apply it to?

Comment: I would be interested in either. Let us be generous and say I can prepare arbitrary many copies of the Choi-state. Also I know the (a priori arbitrary) input state and could in principle prepare arbitray many copies of that, too.

In the end, of course, all resources and execution time should stay polynomial.

Comment: In that case, what prevents me from doing tomography?

Comment: For a full state tomography, I would need exponentially many copies, wouldn't I? If I did shadow tomography, I would be limited in the observables I can predict.

Comment: True, but it still seems to suggest that in a setting where you want to apply a channel many times to a set of input states you can prepare, the times you need to request the Choi state of the channel (if that is the cost) goes to a constant, or only grows very moderatly, with the number of applications.

Comment: Maybe my viewpoint is too naive, but as I see it, you will need at least one copy of the Choi state for each measurement (say you want to measure an obervable $O$ on the output state $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$) as it collapses after the measurement. So if you need exponentially many measurements, you will need exponentially many copies of the Choi-state.

But even if you could reuse the Choi-state, an exponentially scaling sample cost makes it infeasible for practical use. Does this mean that you should in reality always directly execute the quantum channel rather than sample from the Choi-state?

Comment: I think it is potentially relevant in which parameter the exponential scaling is - the dimension of the Hilbert space on which the channel acts? If you want to know how many Choi states you need to apply the channel once, then this seems to have different answer than when you ask that you want to apply the channel N>>1 times, and you want to know how many Choi states you need per channel application. I would thus think that the answer to the question depends on the precise setting.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the ambiguities in my question @NorbertSchuch. I tried to reformulate it based on your comments. In fact, I am interested in a practical real world application that will include the measurement of some observable $O$ on the output state $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$, so yes, the sample complexity will be defining the cost together with other resources such as qubits/copies of the state/gates. If any of this grows exponential in the system size, I would consider the process inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Why do you call 1/d an "exponential factor"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146840/discussion-between-refik-mansuroglu-and-norbert-schuch).